# vector-matrix-vector product properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-calculus

Let $\mathbf{k},\mathbf{h}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{M}$ is a $n \times n$ positive semi-definite matrix.

1. Is this hold?

$$\mathbf{k}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{h} = \mathbf{h}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{k}$$

2. Can I replace $\mathbf{h}$ with $\mathbf{k}$ in the following?

$$\mathbf{h}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{k} \mathbf{k}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{h} = \mathbf{h}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{h} \mathbf{k}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{k}$$

I appreciate if you could answer this with mathematical proof. And by the way, is there a special name for $\mathbf{k}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{h}$ combination?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you working with with real or complex matrices? In general 1) holds when you work with real numbers, 2) does not generally hold (since $\mathbf k \mathbf h^T \neq \mathbf h \mathbf k^T$ in general). By $\mathbf h_*^T$, do you mean the conjugate transpose?

Comment: As for the name, I would call the combination $\mathbf k^T \mathbf M \mathbf h$ a bilinear form. (ps. I believe $\mathbf k$ and $\mathbf h$ should be $n \times 1$ instead of $1 \times n$)

Comment: I meant for a general positive semi-definite matrix as assumed in the question, but I could've been clearer.

Comment: @Rushy asterisk was a typo mistake. I removed it. Also you are right about $n \times 1$. I think if $k$ and $h$ are real, $kh^T = hk^T$ always hold.

Comment: @MaryamBahrami Take $\mathbf k = (1, 0)^T$ and $\mathbf h = (0, 1)^T$, then $\mathbf k \mathbf h^T$ is the $2 \times 2$ matrix with a 1 in the top-right corner, rest $0$, but $\mathbf h \mathbf k^T$ is its transpose. That is; $(\mathbf h \mathbf k^T)^T =\mathbf k \mathbf h^T $ so you have equality iff $\mathbf k \mathbf h^T$ is symmetric.

Comment: It's weird that nobody has commented on it yet @MaryamBahrami, but $\mathbf{k}^\top \mathbf{M}\mathbf{h}$ is not just a bilinear form, but it's actually the most general form of an [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition) on $\Bbb{R}^n$ (since we are assuming $\mathbf{M}$ is $n \times n$ and positive-definite). From this, one can actually conclude that $\mathbf{h}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{k} \mathbf{k}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{h} \le \mathbf{h}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{h} \mathbf{k}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{k}$, which is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality!

Comment: @TheoBendit It was a very complete answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

**Point 1:** First of all, I have seen you agree that $\mathbf{h}$ and $\mathbf{k}$ are **column vectors**, i.e., $n \times 1$ vectors:

A **sufficient** condition for $\mathbf{k}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{h} = \mathbf{h}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{k}$ to hold is that $M$ is symmetrical. Indeed, as the LHS and the RHS are real numbers, and by the fact that a number is equal to its transpose :

$$\mathbf{k}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{h}=(\mathbf{k}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{h})^T = \mathbf{h}^T \mathbf{M}^T \mathbf{k}=\mathbf{h}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{k}\tag{1}$$

**Point 2:** If you are used to notations of bilinear/quadratic forms, your second relationship reads :

$$B(\mathbf{h},\mathbf{k})^2=B(\mathbf{h},\mathbf{h}).B(\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k})\tag{2}$$

If relationship (2) holds (and (1) holds as well), the answer is "yes, you can exchange $h$ and $k$". But if your question is "does (2) holds whatever $k$ and $h$", the answer is "no, in general" (unless for example when $h=k$).

Comment: I don't think point $2$ necessarily holds even when point $1$ holds. Consider the matrix $A = \left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 \\ 2 & 3
\end{matrix}\right)$, $h = (1, 0)^T$, $k = (0, 1)^T$. Then $B(v, w) = v^TAw$ satisfies $B(h, k)^2 = 4$, but $B(h, h)B(k, k) = 3$.

Comment: @Rushy I realize that there was an ill-referencing ((1) instead of (2)). I just correct it.

Comment: Ah yes, if we assume (2) holds then they can be exchanged. I'm actually not sure either if the original question is whether (2) holds or whether we can exchange given it holds.